# Verificar a quantidade de elementos negativos em uma array JS

Tags: javascript, if, for

Estou inciando os estudos em Javascript e me deparo com uma questão em que eu preciso identificar elementos negativos num array e retornar a quantidade desses numeros. Lembrando que podem existir arrays vazios, mistos(+ e - ), negativos e positivos.

Eu tentei fazer com esse aqui, mas não está funcionando:

```
   function quantidadeDeMesesComPerda(umPeriodo){
  let quantidade =0;
  let somaDeElementosNeg = 0;
  let somaDeElementosPosit=0;
  let elementos =0;
  for(var i = 0; i < umPeriodo.length; i++){  
    elementos = umPeriodo[i];
    somaDeElementosNeg+=i;
    somaDeElementosPosit-=i;
        if(elementos < 0){
          quantidade = somaDeElementosNeg;
            return quantidade.length;
      } else if(elementos >0){
        quantidade = somaDeElementosPosit;
            return quantidade.length - somaDeElementosNeg.length;;
      } else {
        return 0;
      }   
  } 
}
```

Comment: Podes dar um exemplo do tipo de arrays que passa à função?

Comment: sim, um dos exemplos que encaixam essa solução é: [10,-10,2,100] ele deveria retornar 1, mas com meu codigo não dá certo.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

O que precisas é:

```js
function quantidadeDeMesesComPerda(umPeriodo) {
  return umPeriodo.filter(nr => nr < 0).length;
}

const test = quantidadeDeMesesComPerda([10, -10, 2, 100]);
console.log(test);
```

Ou seja, com o `.filter` percorres a array e excluis todos os numeros positivos ou zero. No final retornando `.length` vais saber quantos não excluídos ficaram.

O código que tens tinha vários problemas... por exemplo:

- `somaDeElementosNeg += i;`

  aqui estás a somar em cada contagem de `i` o que não faz sentido pois umPeriodo[i] pode ser positivo ou negativo
- `return quantidade.length;`

  um numero não tem `.length`, o que queres é o proprio "quantidade" sem `.length`
  outro problema é o `return` ele vai cancelar o "for loop" e dar-te resposta antes de analisar os elementos todos...

Se quiseres fazer isso com um `for`, usando uma variável incremental podes fazer assim:

```js
function quantidadeDeMesesComPerda(umPeriodo) {
  let perdas = 0;
  for (let i = 0, l = umPeriodo.length; i < l; i++) {
    if (umPeriodo[i] < 0) perdas++;
  }
  return perdas;
}

const test = quantidadeDeMesesComPerda([10, -10, 2, 100]);
console.log(test);
```

Answer (score 3):

## Usando for of.

```js
function quantidadeDeMesesComPerda(umPeriodo){
  var contador = 0;
  for(var item of umPeriodo) {
     if (item < 0) contador ++;
  } 
  return contador;
}

console.log("Meses com perda: " + quantidadeDeMesesComPerda([-1,5,3,8,5,-5,-6,-10]));
```

Pode ser feito com o laço de iteração [`for...of`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of). O laço `for...of` percorre objetos iterativos (incluindo Array, Map, Set, o objeto arguments e assim por diante), chamando instruções em bloco de declarações a serem executadas para o valor de cada objeto distinto.

No exemplo iniciei o `contador` em zero e usei `for of` para percorrer cada item da array `umPeriodo`, para cada item verifique se era um negativo, caso fosse um negativo adicionei um ao contador, caso o contrario passava para outro elemento. No final apenas retornei o valor desse contador.

## Sintaxe

```
for (variavel of iteravel) {
    declarações
}
```

*variável*

A cada iteração, um valor diferente de `iteravel` é atribuído à variável.

*iteravel*

Objeto cujos atributos serão iterados.

---

## Usando reduce.

```js
function quantidadeDeMesesComPerda(umPeriodo){
    return umPeriodo.reduce((acumulador, valorAtual )=>{
       return  (valorAtual < 0)? acumulador + 1 : acumulador;
    }, 0);
}

console.log("Meses com perda: " + quantidadeDeMesesComPerda([-1,5,3,8,5,-5,-6,-10]));
```

Pode ser feito com [`Array.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce). O método `reduce()`executa uma função redutora provida por você para cada membro do array, somando ou diminuindo o acumulador,ou aplicando operações complexas, de acordo com suas necessidades.

No exemplo iniciei o acumulador em zero e cada valor negativo encontrado eu retornava 'acumulador + 1' ou apena `acumulador` caso o valor fosse um positivo ou se não fosse um número e esse valor é repassado automaticamente por `reduce()` para próxima iteração.

## Sintaxe

```
array.reduce(callback[, valorInicial])
```

*callback*

Função que é executada em cada valor no array, recebe quatro argumentos:

*valorInicial*

Opcional. Objeto a ser usado como o primeiro argumento da primeira chamada da função callback. Chamar reduce() em uma array vazia sem valor inicial é um erro.

**Os parâmetros do callback são:**

*Acumulador*

O valor retornado na última invocação do callback, ou o argumento Valor Inicial, se 
fornecido. (exemplo abaixo).

*valorAtual*

O elemento atual que está sendo processado no array.

*indice*

O índice do elemento atual que está sendo processado no array.

*array*

O array ao qual a função reduce() foi chamada.

Comment: há alguma forma de resolver usamos apenas For e If ?

Comment: Tem sim @StéphanieVerissimo, nesse exato momento estou fechando o escritório, mas quando chegar em casa escrevo a solução com if e for. Ok?

Comment: ok, fico no aguardo. vlw

Comment: Acabei fazendo, vou colocar agora, quando chegar em casa  coloco um tecto explicativo.

Comment: que rapidez, eu estou há quase 2 dias tentando resolver esse exercicio

Comment: Já editei a resposta é o primeiro exemplo. Agora fui!

Answer (score 2):

Um jeito simples de fazer isso seria assim, usando o [forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach).
É tão simples quanto o for, creio que você levaria 10 minutos estudando sua estrutura.

```js
function verifyArray(arr) {
    let elemNegative = 0, elemPositive = 0
    arr.forEach((element) => (element > 0 ? elemPositive++ : elemNegative++)) 
    return `Foram encontrados [${elemPositive}] positivo(s) e [${elemNegative}] negativo(s)`
}

console.log(verifyArray([1,2,3,4,5,-5,-6]))
```

Comment: Eu pesquisei videos e pelo google sobre o forEach, mas como sou praticamente leiga nisso tudo e estou aprendendo sozinha fica um pouco dificil de entender assim de primeira. Vc sabe se há alguma resolução só com for e if?

Answer (score 1):

```
function quantidadeDeMesesComPerda(umPeriodo){
   let quantidade = 0;

   for( let i=0;i<umPeriodo.length;i++){
       if(umPeriodo[i]<0){
          quantidade = quantidade + 1
    }
    }
           return quantidade;
    }
```

Comment: Acho que era isso que você buscava...

Comment: Melhore essa endentação e explique para o usuário em que esse código é diferente do código da resposta aceita.

Answer (score 1):

// Loop "FOR" para verificar um array que contem numeros negativos e positivos e exibir eles.
// Exemplo 1:

```
let listaDeGanhos = [10, 30, -10, -5, 40, 8, -2, -10, -15]
let totalNegativos = 0
let totalPositivos = 0 

for(i = 0; i < listaDeGanhos.length; i++) {
    if(listaDeGanhos[i] < totalNegativos) {
        totalNegativos++ // incrementa os numeros negativos do array
    } else {
        listaDeGanhos[i] > totalPositivos
        totalPositivos++
    }
}
                                                
if(totalNegativos === totalPositivos) {
        console.log(totalNegativos + " Mes Negativos", totalPositivos + " Mes Positivos")  
    }else if(totalNegativos > totalPositivos) {
        console.log(totalNegativos + " Mes Negativos")
    }else {
        console.log(totalPositivos + " Mes Positivos")
}
```